# Does a csvde exported file using unicode lose characters if converted from UTF-16 LE (using -u) to UTF-8?

Tags: csv, unicode, utf-8, active-directory, utf-16

This is the scenario:

- Active Directory export using csvde and -u switch (for unicode)
- Output is a UTF-16 LE file.
- Some Chinese and Arabic characters are exported successfully.
- "Save as" UTF-8 using Windows Notepad.
- Chinese and Arabic characters show up correctly.

Assuming csvde creators chose UTF-16 to avoid losing characters when exporting. Do we potentially lose characters when converting with notepad to UTF-8? If so, what characters, could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-32, UTF-16, and UTF-8 all support the full range of Unicode code points.  No loss.

FYI, "Unicode" on Windows often really means UTF-16. The APIs are internally using UTF-16.